# Deduce controller name from namespaced string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

At some point in my Rails codebase I'm using the following:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referer)
```

My goal is to get the class object of the `:controller` key.
So far I've only gotten to something like this: `my/namespace/posts`.

The true class however is `My::Namespace::PostsController`. Is there any way to automatically deduce the class name?
Otherwize, what't the most elegant way to get to that?

Comment: path.split("/"}.map { |e| e.titleize}.join("::").concat("Controller")

Comment: You might want to use `classify` instead of `titleize` to make it work with snake case names of files and directories. (`name_space` -> `NameSpace`)

Comment: Have you tried request.controller_class?

Comment: There are two fundamental problems with this idea - browsers don't always send the HTTP_REFERER header and `recognize_path` doesn't actually reliably tell you which controller processed the previous request as it doesn't take the HTTP method or constraints into consideration. If you want to do this in a way that will actually work reliably store the data about the previous request (like the URI and what controller it was processed by) in the session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@zakariah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11964190/zakariah1) mentioned [`ActionDispatch::Request#controller_class`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-controller_class) which appears like it should work provided that `params[:controller]` is a `String`,  although I have not tested it:

```
params = {controller: '/my/namespace/posts'}
ActionDispatch::Request.new({}).controller_class_for(params[:controller])
#=> My::Namespace::PostsController
request.controller_class # in theory 
#=> My::Namespace::PostsController
```

however this will raise an error if the controller does not exist.

That being said based on your current implementation, you have managed to get to the String `"my/namespace/posts"`, which means you are 90% of the way there.

To convert this to the desired controller name is actually fairly simple:

```
str = "my/namespace/posts" 
controller_name = str.camelize << "Controller" 
#=> "::My::Namespace::PostsContoller"
contoller_name.safe_constantize
#=> ::My::Namespace::PostsContoller
```

This is a simple inversion of [`AbstractController::Base#controller_path`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Base.html#method-c-controller_path), which uses `underscore`.

As mentioned in the docs:

[`ActiveSupport::Inflector::camelize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-camelize)

> [`camelize`] Also converts '/' to '::' which is useful for converting paths to namespaces....

**Important Note**:

> ...As a rule of thumb you can think of `camelize` as the inverse of `underscore`, though there are cases where that does not hold:
>
> `camelize(underscore('SSLError'))  # => "SslError"`

So you will need to ensure that the proper inflections are setup if needed in your application.

I chose to use `safe_constantize` which will return `nil` if the constant does not exist. This allows you to handle these issues (missing constants) in a more idiomatic fashion e.g.

```
controller_name.safe_constantize || DefaultContoller
```